# Please explain this formula for the relationship between bandwidth and the temporal response of a photodetector

Tags: noise, signal, photodiode, bandwidth, photosensor

I am reading ["Optoelectronic Sensors" by Didier Decoster and Joseph Harari](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470611630).

At section 1.8.2 they start explaining the relationship between rise time and bandwidth, and they give a very weird formula that I don't understand:

[image: Image showing section 1.8.2 of the referenced book]

That's the whole thing, they don't explain anything more. Then they move on to some very interesting things about noise, but they mention BP in there and I don't understand what it is.

Now, my understanding about bandwidth and rise time came from [this website](https://interferencetechnology.com/rise-time-vs-bandwidth-and-applications/#), specifically equation 18 that basically says:

$$
t_r = \frac{0.35}{B}
$$

where \$t_r\$ is rise time and \$B\$ is bandwidth.

With that in mind, here is what I don't understand about the equation 1.7 in "Optoelectronic Sensors":

1. What is BP and how is it different from BW?
2. Is \$\tau\$ (tau) the rise/fall time? Or is it something else?
3. What are \$\tau_m\$ (tau_m) and \$\tau_d\$ (tau_d)? They didn't mention them anywhere before.

Answer (score 3):

The equations shown are all derived from the same formula which you already gave:

$$t_r = \frac{0.35}{B}$$

A single-pole system has the frequency response

$$H(s) = \frac{A}{1 + \tau\cdot s}$$

This sytem has a pole at

$$p_d = \frac{1}{\tau} \Rightarrow BW = \frac{1}{2\pi\cdot \tau}$$

The transient step response of this system can be calculated as

$$h_{out} = A\left(1 - e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}\right)$$

From which you can calculate a timepoint for each output value:

$$t = -\tau\cdot\ln\left(1 - \frac{h_{out}}{A}\right)$$

If you'd rather use the rise/fall time instead of \$\tau\$, you can then easily calculate that

$$\tau_r = -\tau\cdot\ln(1-0.9) + \tau\cdot\ln(1-0.1) = \tau \ln(9) \approx 2.1972\cdot \tau$$

Hence

$$BW = \frac{1}{2\pi\cdot \tau} = \frac{\ln(9)}{2\pi\cdot \tau_r} = \frac{\ln(9)}{2\pi\cdot \tau_f}$$

The abbreviations are the ones used in French. "**B**ande **P**assante" (BP) means bandwidth, "**M**onter" (\$\tau_m\$) means to rise, "**D**escendre" (\$\tau_d\$) means to fall.

Answer (score 1):

For a first order system, the bandwidth is equal to the cut-off frequency:
$$ B = f_c $$
The rise time \$ \tau_r\$ (respecting the symbols used on book):
$$ \tau_r \approx \frac{0.35}{B}$$
The system time constant is \$ \tau\$, or:
$$ \tau = \frac{1}{\omega_c} = \frac{1}{2 \pi f_c} = \frac{1}{2 \pi B} $$
Or:
$$ B = \frac{1}{2 \pi \tau} $$
Replacing \$ B \$ in expression for rise time \$\tau_r \$ (similar for \$ \tau_f\$):
$$ \tau_r \approx \frac{0.35}{\frac{1}{2 \pi \tau}} $$
Also:
$$ \tau_r \approx 2.2\tau $$

In terms of \$ B \$:

$$ B = \frac{2.2}{2 \pi \tau_r}  = \frac{2.2}{2 \pi \tau_f} $$

My guess is that the text seems to confuse some terms (see the last sentence, for example). If this is correct you can have \$ B = BP \$, \$ \tau_r = \tau_m \$ and \$ 
\tau_f = \tau_d \$.

Comment: @Fernando Franco Félix: I didn't describe how the equation tr = 0.35/B was obtained, since would be unnecessary (it had already been done in the link you provided on question).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the basic photo-detector (photo-diode) below.
[image: Equivalent circuit of a photodiode]

Image credit: Wikipedia

Now this equivalent circuit can be simplified into:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJG1Uo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This can be equivalently modeled again as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDDNnh.png)</sup>

Where,
\begin{equation}
I_1 = I_D \pm I_{PH} \pm I_R
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
V_1 = I_1 \times R
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
R = R_P || (R_S+R_L)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
C_1 = C_S
\end{equation}
Now, applying the mesh equation (Kirchoff's Voltage Law) in the second image,
\begin{equation}
V_1 = I_1 R + \frac{1}{C} \int I_1(t) \text{dt}
\end{equation}
where, \$ V_0 \$ is the output voltage taken across the capacitor.
Taking Laplace transform on both sides,
\begin{equation}
V_1 (s) = I_1 (s)R + \frac{I_1(s)}{Cs}
\end{equation}
Assuming the capacitor in uncharged initially,
\begin{equation}
\frac{V_1(S)}{V_o(s)} = RCs + 1
\end{equation}
Thus, the transfer function is given by
\begin{equation}
G(s) = \frac{1}{1+RCs} = \frac{V_0(s)}{V_1(s)}
\end{equation}
Assuming that the input light intensity is constant and thus giving a constant current and hence giving a equivalent constant modeled voltage \$ V_1(s) = \frac{V}{s} \$, we get,
\begin{equation}
V_0(s) = \frac{V}{s(1+RCs)}
\end{equation}
Taking inverse Laplace transform, we get
\$ V_0(t) = V\big(1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}\big) \$
Or equivalently,
\begin{equation} V_0(t) = V\Bigg(1-e^{-\frac{(R_S+R_P+R_L)t}{R_P(R_S+R_L)C_S}}\Bigg)
\end{equation}
Now rise time is defined as the time taken for the output to reach \$ 90%\$ of the output from \$ 10%\$ of its value. That is, difference between time when \$ V_0(t) = 0.9 V_1(t) \$ and time when \$ V_0(t) = 0.1 V_1(t) \$
Thus, 
\begin{equation}
0.9 = 1-e^{-\frac{t_1}{RC}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
0.1 = 1-e^{-\frac{t_2}{RC}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
t_1 = -\ln(0.1)\tau
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
t_2 = -\ln(0.9)\tau
\end{equation}
The rise time is 
\begin{equation}
t_r = t_1-t_2 = \ln(9) \tau
\end{equation}
where, \$\tau = RC\$.
Since, this time constant \$ \tau = \frac{1}{2\pi\times\text{Bandwidth}} \$,
\begin{equation}
t_r = \frac{\ln(9)}{2\pi\times BW} = \frac{0.3496991526}{BW} \approx \frac{0.35}{BW}
\end{equation}

Comment: what is \$R_P\$ in the equivalent circuit?

Comment: As you see the construction of the photodiode as considered here, it has a p-n junction. Intrinsically, there is a depletion layer that has several components which are parasitic capacitance, series and parallel resistances namely \$R_S\$ and \$R_P\$ , with dark current \$I_D\$, noise current \$I_R\$ and photocurrent \$I_{PH}\$ and diode capacitance \$C_S\$. \$R_L\$ is the load resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Tektronix Corporation suggested their scopes, perhaps rated at 10MHz, with a number of internal poles establishing that 10MHz bandwidth, would have a risetime of 0.35/10MHz.

Comment: Using the equation firmly establishes that the response is a single-pole filter, not "a number of internal poles" (unless the number is one).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What is BP and how is it different from BW?

Probably means "Bandwidth of Photodetector", regardless the author wrote poorly and did not define the term. They also wrote a bad equation and didn't explain where they got the rise time factor. If you compare the detective equation 1.11 to the [equation for detectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_detectivity) a better definition would be \$\frac{1}{2\pi\tau}=BP=\Delta f\$

[image]
source: https://www.picotech.com/library/oscilloscopes/rise-time

> Is tau the rise/fall time?, or is it something else?

Tau is the time it takes to get from 10% to 90%, or the rise/fall time.

\$\log(0.90)-\log(0.10)=2.197\$ or 2.2